# Bucket 2 columns of data (character class) into a newly created column in R

Tags: r

I will like to bin data from Column A (rideable_type) and Column B (member_casual) into column C (a newly created column called type_of_users). For instance, if Column A is electric_bike and Column B is member, I will like to show, in Column C, as member_electric. I have googled for a suitable code but nothing seems to work. Seeking anyone who can help me on this issue.  Below are some details which may be vital:

- Dataset name: df1
- Column A (rideable_type) and Column B (member_casual): Given dataset. Both class and mode are “Characters”.
- Column C (type_of_users): End result that I wish to achieve. Both class and mode are to be "Character”.

[Dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQtYL.jpg)

I tried with the below code but it duplicate itself on the right hand side of the dataset.

```
df1$type_of_users %>% 
  mutate(case_when
         (df1$member_casual =='casual' & df1$rideable_type =='docked_bike' ~ 'casual_docked',
           df1$member_casual =='member' & df1$rideable_type =='docked_bike' ~ 'member_docked',
           df1$member_casual =='casual' & df1$rideable_type =='electric_bike' ~ 'casual_electric',
           df1$member_casual =='member' & df1$rideable_type =='electric_bike' ~ 'member_electric'))
```

If this isn't the suitable one, what other kinds will be useful? If function? Stack function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do much simpler like this:

```
data <- data.frame('rideable_type' = c('electric_bike','docked_bike','docked_bike', 'electric_bike'), 'member_casual' = c('member','casual','casual','member')) 

# columns to paste together
cols <- c( 'rideable_type' , 'member_casual'  )

# create a new column `x` with the three columns collapsed together
data$type_of_users <- apply( data[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "_" )

#clean with gsub to remove or substiture any string
data$type_of_users <- gsub("_bike", "", data$type_of_users)
```